# one route 2 controllers - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route, based on the term i need to call the appropriate controller. 
for e.g

```
Route::get('/{term}','Usercontroller')
Route::get('/{term}','brandcontroller')
```

i want to achieve some thing like this. what the term holds is a name(string), based on this string it either belongs to User table or brand table. how can i achieve something like this using Service Container. that before deciding on which route to take, based on the term if it belongs to USER class, the usercontroller should be called, or if it belongs to brand class , brandcontroller route should be taken.
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: you should probably use another URL structure. such as `/user/{term}` that will make it harder for bugs to appear and it will make your site more structured in it's entirety.

Comment: I would suggest, why don't you go for simpler approch, /brand/{term}

Comment: this was just an example, but the question remains, based on the term i need to decide which controller to call.

Comment: This might be help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Comment: as i have described in the description of the question, how can i achieve this using Service container, before Laravel decides which route to take.before the route is decide, i want to know that the term belongs to one of the class. 
`Route::get('/{term}','Usercontroller')->wheremodelis('term',User::Class)`
`Route::get('/{term}','Brandcontroller')->wheremodelis('term',Brand::Class)`

Comment: Well anyways u could easy add one symbol before term: U{term}, B{term}.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili can you expand on what you commented?

Comment: For example when you generate urls, if term belongs to user you prepend `U` to the term, and if its the brand `B`. and in routes you can easily do:  `Route::get('B{term}', 'BrandController');` and `Route::get('U{term}', 'UserController');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create middleware IsBrand, & check if brand exists?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'IsBrand'], function () {
    Route::get('{term}', 'BrandController');
});
```

Same goes for IsUser.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'IsUser'], function () {
    Route::get('{term}', 'UserController');
});
```

Use `php artisan make:middleware IsBrand` to create middleware.

This command will place a new `IsBrand` class within your `app/Http/Middleware` directory.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsBrand
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (App\Brand::where('brand_name', $term)->count())) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should also give example for the middleware

Comment: This is useful and works totally, but i don't want to access DB in middleware, is there any way other than middleware ?

Comment: @MuhammadImran I do not know, buddy. If you find, please let me know.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Thanks for the suggestion bro.

Comment: @moraya.re very welcome, thanks for considering it :))